# Getting data from external program

Tags: python

I need a method to get the data from an external editor.

```
def _get_content():
     from subprocess import call
     file = open(file, "w").write(some_name)
     call(editor + " " + file, shell=True)
     file.close()
     file = open(file)
     x = file.readlines()

     [snip]
```

I personally think there should be a more elegant way. You see, I need to interact with an external editor and get the data.

Do you know any better approaches/have better ideas?

EDIT:

Marcelo brought me on the idea of using `tempfile` for doing that.

Here's how I do it:

```
def _tempfile_write(input):
    from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

    x = NamedTemporaryFile()
    x.file.write(input)
    x.close()
    y = open(x)

    [snip]
```

This does the job, but also not quite satisfying. *Heard something about spawning?..*

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what do you find ugly about this approach? Is it "I need the user to type in some text and get that text as a string"? Is it "I need the user to edit a pre-existing file"? Are you asking how to spawn a new editor process or how to get input from the user?

Comment: I'm talking about the getting input from the user. :) I admit ugly is not the right word... maybe saying, I'm searching for a more elegant way doing this (if there is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a list, not a string:

```
def _get_content(editor, initial=""):
    from subprocess import call
    from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

    # Create the initial temporary file.
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tf:
        tfName = tf.name
        tf.write(initial)

    # Fire up the editor.
    if call([editor, tfName]) != 0:
        return None # Editor died or was killed.

    # Get the modified content.
    with open(tfName).readlines() as result:
        os.remove(tfName)
        return result
```

Comment: Gah, forgot the justification: You want to use a list to `call` and `shell=False` because then you don't have to worry about escaping any characters in the filename (space, `&`, `;`, etc.) that the shell gives special meaning to.  Granted, `NamedTemporaryFile` shouldn't give you a filename with those characters, but it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way all programs do it, AFAIK. Certainly all version control systems that I've used create a temporary file, pass it to the editor and retrieve the result when the editor exits, just as you have.

Comment: Mentioning temporary files was good.. I found a good Python module on that named ``tempfile``. I think this sounds great for the start.

Answer (score 1):

an editor just lets you edit a file interactively. you can also edit files with Python. there's no need to call external editor.

```
for line in open("file"):
    print "editing line ", line
    # eg replace strings
    line = line.replace("somestring","somenewstring")
    print line
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. Though I need to get user input and then immediately process that data, storing it all in a database, otherwise I'd do it just that way. :)